# Error 500 on uploading pdf

Tags: php, upload, runtime-error

My site throws an Error 500 when uploading a pdf.

I have gone into the php.ini page and changed

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2m
```

to

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 100m
```

Yet it still throws the 500 error. I'm at a loss as to why my server won't allow this.

I should also state the file I'm testing this with is only 50kb.

EDIT:

---

The source of this error has lead to another question I had but wasn't quite ready to figure it out. Anyways, here it goes.

I am having the user verify the contents of the pdf they uploaded, and then I want to pass it to another page to save the file to a local drive.

The error the log is throwing is

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in updatePDF-check.php on line 36
```

Line 36 is as follows

```
echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'uploadedFile' value = '".$_FILES['file']."'">;
```

Which leads to the question. How should I have this page display the file, and then pass it on to the next page so that it can be saved?

double edit, fixed the typo in the above line, but my question still stands I believe

```
echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'uploadedFile' value = '".$_FILES['file']."'>";
```

It should be worth stating that `display_errors` was also turned off in the php.ini file. So I have turned that on as well

Comment: Look in the server logs what the message behind the 500 error is all about

Comment: would that be event viewer?

Comment: No, find your Apache Error Log (assuming you're using Apache), delete it, then run the code again. Then post the contents of the new file here.

Comment: IIS. but I'm assuming the process is the same. I'll go find that log

Comment: added error logs, which changed the direction of the question due to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parse error will be fixed with this:

```
echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'uploadedFile' value = '".$_FILES['file']."'>";
```

Your > was one char too far to the right :)

Comment: I caught that error right after I pressed the submit (90% of my errors are dumb typos. See updated question

Comment: I'd recommend saving your file in the same script (without sending headers), and then display it to the user directly after that. So, one script without the need to forward on.

Comment: Either that or save the file, and do a header("Location: ") to the 'display this file' page, where you can pass the filename argument as a GET.

Comment: If I could trouble you for another green checkmark, I'm a little confused by what you've just said. So I've created a different question for it, as it is in fact a different question than what was asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559981/have-user-validate-file-before-saving-to-server

Comment: It should be worth stating that `display_errors` was also turned off in the php.ini file. So I have turned that on as well